# position div to bottom of visible container with hidden overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a div which contains an image. The idea is that the user will be able to press a button and the div expands to a specific height. So what I did was set the height of the container to `200px` while the image has a height of `400px`. I want to add a little button to the bottom right of the container.

The problem is that the button appears underneath the image.

So my question is, how do I have the button `div`  stick to the bottom of the container it is in?

```
.visual {
    padding: 0;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pull-down-button {
    float:right;
}

.visual img {width: 100%}

<div class="visual">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400" />
    <div class="pull-down-button">some text</div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/n3zkov64/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set position:relative on the parent div (.visual), then remove the float on the child and change the position from relative to absolute on the child div (.pull-down-button). Also note that you need to specify units for the right property:

```
.visual {
    padding: 0;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.pull-down-button {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:10px;
}
.visual img {
    width: 100%
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/n3zkov64/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like now?

So, i made some changes:

```
.pull-down-button {
    position:absolute;  
    z-index: 10000;
    bottom:0;
    right:10;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n3zkov64/6/

Comment: Absolute positioning and floating together don't make sense.

Comment: Why is the z-index necessary? And what does 10 as a value for right mean? You need a unit.

Comment: It seems that I understood bad what Ortixx requested for help.